# AutoHotkey FileGetTime Access ScreenShot

Tags: autohotkey

Here is my script i've written so far. It only partially works.
I need it to take a screen shot of the pc only after an alarm is played. When I run the script it takes a screen shot instantly, saves it under the proper file name and location, and closes mspaint. It will then loop every 20 seconds and take another. Something is wrong with my while command that i just can't figure out. How i'm reading my syntax it should stay in the while loop until Elapsed is less than 20 seconds. Then once the file is accessed exit the while loop and continue down the infinite loop.

```
Loop {

    FileGetTime, LastTime, alarm.wav, A
    Elapsed := A_Now - LastTime

    while (Elapsed > 20000){
        FileGetTime, LastTime, alarm.wav, A
        Elapsed := A_Now - LastTime
    }

    send {PrintScreen}
    Run, MSPaint
    WinWaitActive, Untitled - Paint
    Send ^v
    Sleep, 50
    Send ^s
    Sleep, 50
    Send c:\Screenshots\
    Send %A_Now%
    Sleep, 100
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep, 2000
    WinClose, ahk_exe MSPaint.exe


    Sleep, 20000

}
```

Comment: Getting file time is counted as **A**ccess, I guess. Try removing `, A`

Comment: No, that "A" is what tells the app to get the "A"ccess time of the file.

Comment: I'm sorry didn't mean for it to come off like that. :)
If I delete the "A" It Defaults to "M" and grabs the modified time of the file. I can't use the modified time, since playing the file doesn't modify it. Also I did check, running the script does not affect the last access time. Showed 4 minutes ago on access time immediately after i closed the script.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by putting a

```
MsgBox %Elapsed%
```

within the while loop. It calculates seconds not Milliseconds. dropped the while equation down to 20 from 20000 and it works now.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

LastTime = 0

Loop 
{

    Elapsed = 30

    while (Elapsed > 20)
    {
        FileGetTime, LastTime, alarm.wav, A
        Elapsed := A_Now - LastTime
    }

    send {PrintScreen}
    Run, MSPaint
    WinWaitActive, Untitled - Paint
    Send ^v
    Sleep, 50
    Send ^s
    Sleep, 200
    Send c:\Screenshots\%A_Now%
    Sleep, 100
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    WinClose, ahk_exe MSPaint.exe


    Sleep, 20000

}
```